# What does it mean to "provide" a set with a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

In the past weeks, I've often read that something is "provided" with a $\sigma$-algebra, but I don't understand what this is supposed to mean. For example, when we say that we provide $\Bbb R$ with the Borel algebra, what do we receive? A new set? And why is this even necessary?

**Edit:**

I would like to give some additional information on what confuses me here. As another example, take a look at one of the tasks we were given.

Let $\Omega \neq \emptyset$ be a set, $(\Xi, \Sigma)$ be a measure space and $f: \Omega \rightarrow \Sigma$ be a map. Define $\sigma(f) := \{f^{-1}(F) : F \in \Sigma \}$.

Now, determine $\sigma(f)$ for $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$, $x \rightarrow x$. In this case, let $\Bbb R$ be provided with the $\sigma$-algebra of the borel sets.

How do I have to undertand this in this specific context?

Comment: It's just that $\sigma(f)$ is something that depends on the sigma algebra you have on $\mathbb R$. If you're using a different sigma algebra, you get a different value of $\sigma(f)$. So they have to specify which sigma algebra is being used, that is, which sigma algebra is "provided".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give examples that might be more familiar:

- Set is a set $A$ "provided" with nothing.
- Functions are functions 
  $f\colon A\to B$.

  ---
- Partially ordered set is a set $P$ "provided" with relation $<$ satisfying familiar axioms.
- Monotone functions are functions $f\colon P\to S$ such that $x<_Py\implies f(x) <_S f(y)$, for all $x,y\in P$.
- We might write $(P,<)$ for partially ordered set and even write $f\colon (P,<_P)\to (S,<_S)$ to denote monotone function with domain $P$ and codomain $S$.

  ---
- Group is a set $G$ "provided" with functions $m\colon G\times G\to G$, $i\colon G\to G$ and $e\colon 1\to G$ (multiplication, inverse and identity) satisfying familiar axioms.
- Homomorphisms are functions $f\colon G\to H$ such that $f(m_G(x,y)) = m_H(f(x),f(y))$, for all $x,y\in G$.
- We might write $(G,m,i,e)$ for group, but I've never seen $f\colon (G,m_G,i_G,e_G)\to (H,m_H,i_H,e_H)$ to denote group homomorphism with domain $G$ and codomain $H$.

  ---
- Vector space over field $k$ is Abelian group $V$ "provided" with function $\pi\colon k\times V\to V$ (scalar multiplication) satisfying familiar axioms.
- Linear maps are group homomorphisms $f\colon V\to W$ such that $f(\pi_V(\alpha,v)) = \pi_W(\alpha,f(v))$, for all $\alpha\in k$, $v\in V$.
- We might write $(V,+_V,\pi_V)$ for vector space and even write $f\colon (V,+_V,\pi_V)\to (W,+_W,\pi_W)$ to denote linear map with domain $V$ and codomain $W$.

  ---
- Topological space is set $X$ "provided" with set $\tau\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ (topology) satisfying familiar axioms.
- Continuous functions are functions $f\colon X\to Y$ such that $f^{-1}(U)\in\tau_X$, for all $U\in\tau_Y$.
- We might write $(X,\tau_X)$ for topological space and even write $f\colon (X,\tau_X)\to (Y,\tau_Y)$ to denote continuous function with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$.

  ---
- Measurable space is set $X$ "provided" with set $\Sigma\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ ($\sigma$-algebra) satisfying familiar axioms.
- Measurable functions are functions $f\colon X\to Y$ such that $f^{-1}(A)\in\Sigma_X$, for all $A\in\Sigma_Y$.
- We might write $(X,\tau_X)$ for measurable space and even write $f\colon (X,\Sigma_X)\to (Y,\Sigma_Y)$ to denote measurable function with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$.

As you can see there is a common theme here. We start with some set, define some structure on it and then define special class of functions that preserve said structure.

To "provide" a set $X$ with $\sigma$-algebra means to find $\Sigma\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$ that satisfies axioms of $\sigma$-algebra. Sometimes familiar sets already have well known structures "provided" to them. For example:

- Set $\Bbb Z$ is Abelian group in a familiar way. We could try to "provide" $\Bbb Z$ with something exotic, but usually we don't.
- Set $\Bbb R^n$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$ when "provided" with familiar group structure and scalar multiplication.
- We could "provide" $\Bbb C$ with structure of real vector space if we wanted: scalar multiplication is just the usual multiplication with real numbers.
- Want a topology on $\Bbb R^n$? You don't have to look further than "providing" it with Euclidean topology.
- And what about making $\Bbb R$ into measurable space? "Provide" it with Borel $\sigma$-algebra!

Hopefully, "providing" will be clear enough by now so that we can stop using quotation marks.

If you have a function $f\colon\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, you can provide codomain with whatever $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ you want. In your case $\Sigma =\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$. Thus $\sigma(f) = \{f^{-1}(A)\mid A\in\mathcal B(\Bbb R)\}$. It might be worth to note that $\sigma(f)$ is $\sigma$-algebra, so we can provide domain with $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(f)$. In this case, $f$ becomes a function between measurable spaces $(\Bbb R,\sigma(f))$ and $(\Bbb R,\mathcal B(\Bbb R))$. Note that $f$ didn't change in any way, its domain is still $\Bbb R$ and its codomain is still $\Bbb R$. They are just provided with (possibly) different $\sigma$-algebras. The natural question is whether $f$ is measurable function with respect to said $\sigma$-algebras. The answer is yes, and $\sigma(f)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra you can provide domain $\Bbb R$ with such that $f$ is measurable (having in mind that $\sigma$-algebra on codomain is fixed).

Answer (score 1):

We get $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$, where $B(\mathbb R))\subset2^\mathbb R$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the topology of $\mathbb R$

In general, the $\sigma$-algebra is a family of subsets of the given set which have the $\sigma$-algebra properties.

We need such a family of subsets because we cannot extend the natural Lebesgue measure, which measures an interval to the length of that interval $\mu([a,b])=b-a$, to the all the subsets of $\mathbb R$ (a famous result, I think due to Ulam). So our $\sigma$-algebra (in fact its completed measure) would be the maximal extension of this natural measure to subsets of $\mathbb R$

Comment: What is $2^{\Bbb R}$ exactly?

Comment: @Borol, set of all subsets of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: So when I have a function $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ and I say that $\Bbb R$ is provided with the Borel algebra, it means that I actually have the function $f: (\Bbb R, \mathscr B(\Bbb R)) \rightarrow (\Bbb R, \mathscr B(\Bbb R))$?

Comment: I honsetly don't understand it, especially in terms of one of the tasks we were given. I find it rather confusing. Give me a second and I'll edit it in the main post to show you what I mean.

Comment: No. The function is still $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$. But if for $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ (on the right) we have the preimage $f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ (on the left), then $f$ is called measurable.

Comment: If your function is the identity, then the preimage of any Borel set is itself, as $f^{-1}(B)=B$. In this case $\sigma$-algebra induced by $f$, called $\sigma(f)$ is the Borel set itself $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$